# How to use a data passed using state in Anguar

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to implement search in my Angular app, receiving my data through a book service, and passing the data using state while navigating to a new component, the data is in form of an array of objects. My challenge here is how to use the data on the new component, the approach below doesn't give me the required result.

**Search input**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  BookService
} from '../services';
import {
  Router
} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'search-input',
  templateUrl: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="searchBooks(searchTerm)">
      <input type="search" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" Search" aria-label="Search">
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class SearchInputComponent implements OnInit {
  searchTerm = '';
  foundBooks: any;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  searchBooks(searchTerm) {
    this.bookService.searchBooks(searchTerm)
      .subscribe(books => {
        this.foundBooks = books;
        console.log(this.foundBooks);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('search-output', {
          state: {
            result: this.foundBooks
          }
        });
      });

  }

}
```

**Search Output**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  map
} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-output',
  templateUrl: `
     <div *ngFor="let state of state$">
       <p>{{state}}</p>
    </div">
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./search-output.component.css']
})
export class SearchOutputComponent implements OnInit {
  state$: Observable < object > ;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
      .pipe(map(() => window.history.state));

    // console.log(this.state$);

  }

}
```

Comment: when you get the data from the api in your service, store it there ( in the service ) by assigning it to a variable. then you can access this variable in another component.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in two way.

1. Using Service  *`This is a best way`*
2. Using Routing

> 1. Using service: `just make setter and getter method in service`

**service.ts**

---

```
bookData: any = [];

setData(data) { // call this method from the component and pass the result you get from the API to set it in the service
  this.bookData = data;
}


getData(data) { // call this method from the component to get the already set data
  return this.bookData;
}
```

---

> 2. Using Routing:

**Search Input**

```
 searchBooks(searchTerm) {
    this.bookService.searchBooks(searchTerm)
      .subscribe(books => {
        this.foundBooks = books;
        console.log(this.foundBooks);
        this.router.navigate(['/component2', {result: this.foundBooks}]); // private router: Router => import Router

      });

  }
```

**Search Output**

```
  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('result')); //private route: ActivatedRoute /=> import ActivatedRoute

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy and simple solution would be to create a variable on BookService and put the search results in that variable and access it from SearchOutputComponent. But I won't recommend it. 
What you need is a State management logic that will allow you to persist data across components. This type of use case will rise more often. There are many ways to implement State management by using fancy libs like ngrx, akita etc., But for a simple application they are overkill. You can use Observable Store Services, simple to implement and use. Below is a blog explaining the concept with nice example 
https://blog.angulartraining.com/tutorial-state-management-with-observable-store-services-5ba53d87ad94

Answer (score 1):

**Complete working** demo you can find here in this [Stack Blitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvaeju?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

- I am giving you solution of passing data between router using `service` and `BehaviorSubject`. Here, we are using `rxjs` approach too. here, when user seach for book-term by name one autoComplete popup shows up. when user select autoComplete result, user is navigate to serach component using router. For passing data in between we are using `behaviorSubject`...

This search method fires when user selects term from autocomplete. and `service sendData()` method is called.

```
    search(term){
       if (term.length > 0) {
          this.serachService.sendData(term);
          this.route.navigate(['/searchoutput']);
       }
    }
```

**Service.ts**

```
export class SearchService {
       searchData$: BehaviorSubject<object[]> = new BehaviorSubject<object[]>([{}]);

       sendData(term){
          // called form app.compoent.ts to send data using .next()
          this.searchData$.next(term)
          this.searchData$.next(term)
       }
       getData(){
          // called form searchoutput component to getData using .asObservable()
          return this.searchData$.asObservable();
       }
}
```

**getting data in searchComponent.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookData$ = this.searchService.getData();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `BehaviourSubject` to achieve this.

**SearchService**

```js
export class SearchService {
  private searchResultStore: BehaviorSubject<object[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

  searchBooks(searchTerm) {
    this.http.post(`Your payload`, `Your url`).pipe(
      tap(books => this.searchResultStore.next(books))
    );
  }

  get searchResult$() {
   this.searchResultStore.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**SearchInputComponent**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookService } from '../services';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'search-input',
  templateUrl: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="searchBooks(searchTerm)">
      <input type="search" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" Search" aria-label="Search">
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class SearchInputComponent implements OnInit {
  searchTerm = '';

  constructor(private bookService: BookService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  searchBooks(searchTerm) {
    this.bookService.searchBooks(searchTerm)
      .subscribe(books => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('search-output');
      });
  }
}
```

**SearchOutputComponent**

use `async` pipe in html to subscribe.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BookService } from '../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-output',
  templateUrl: `
     <div *ngFor="let state of bookService.searchResult$ | async">
       <p>{{state}}</p>
    </div">
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./search-output.component.css']
})
export class SearchOutputComponent {
  constructor(public bookService: BookService) {}
}
```